# Functions with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to write a function template that can take variable number of template arguments, and just print out the typeid().name() of the type parameters. I can do something like that using static functions inside class templates as follows :

```
template<typename...>
struct foo;

template<typename H, typename... T>
struct foo<H, T...> {
  static void print() {
    std::cout << typeid(H).name() << ", ";
    foo<T...>::print();
  }
};

template<typename H>
struct foo<H> {
  static void print() {
    std::cout << typeid(H).name() << "\n";
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  foo<int, float>::print();
  return 0;
}
```

However, I am not able to do the following :

```
template<typename H, typename... T>
void print() {
  std::cout << typeid(H).name() << ", ";
  print<T...>();
}
int main(void)
{
  print<int, float>();
  return 0;
}
```

I tried adding the following "base" cases :

```
template<typename H>
void print();
```

and

```
void print();
```

Neither worked. How do I write such a function template?

Comment: What error message were you getting?

Comment: Your class template specializations are ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I could get the following code to compile with Clang 3.1 and [GCC 4.5.1](http://ideone.com/1JVQ0):

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void print(){
  std::cout << typeid(T).name();
}

template<typename H, typename T, typename... R>
void print(){
  std::cout << typeid(H).name() << ", ";
  print<T, R...>();
}

int main(){
  print<int, float>();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. It didn't occur to me that handling 2 or more template arguments in the main case, and handling 1 argument in the base case is the right solution. I was trying to do 1 or more in the general case and 0 in the base case. The main take away, for me at least, is typename... A matches 0 or more arguments.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> template<typename H>
> void print();
> ```

This won't work because it is ambiguous with the variadic overload: both can be called with a single template argument.

> ```
> void print();
> ```

This doesn't work because in your variadic `print` you're calling `print<T...>` which can only ever match a `print` template, not a regular function (even when `T...` expands to an empty argument list, the call will be `print<>()`, not `print()`.)

One solution is to change your variadic case to only accept at least two arguments:

```
template<typename H, typename T1, typename... TRest>
void print() {
  std::cout << typeid(H).name() << ", ";
  print<T1, T...>();
}
```

Now your one-argument `print` template should be correctly selected at the bottom of the recursion.

I *think* the following should work in C++11 as a zero-argument base case, but I couldn't get gcc 4.6 to accept it:

```
template<> void print();
```

Answer (score -2):

You could alternatively do this:

```
void print() {/*...*/} 

template<typename X>   void print() {/*...*/} 

template<typename X, typename Y>   void print() {/*...*/} 

int main()
{
  print();
  print<int>();
  print<int,double>();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle more than 2 template arguments.